# How to turn on the access log for Spring WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

For Spring WebFlux running on Netty I want to have access logs like in Tomcat, but I find nothing in the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html).

Can anyone help?

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing pre-built for Netty-based servers in Spring Boot. The closest thing you could get out of the box is Netty wire log by switching log levels of `reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ContextHandler` and `reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServer` to `DEBUG`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has been implemented in Netty v0.7.9.RELEASE following [this issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/301). According to the instructions posted [here](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/301#issuecomment-418402375) you can enable the log so:

- Run your application with `-Dreactor.netty.http.server.accessLogEnabled=true` system property

AND

- Enable INFO logging of `reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog`

Note that only [CLF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) is supported for the moment.

Other solutions, available before that feature was implemented, are eg.:

## Wire log

As @GreyTeardrop mentioned in the comment, you can set the log level of `reactor.ipc.netty.channel.ContextHandler` and `reactor.ipc.netty.http.server.HttpServer` to `DEBUG`. This will produce a multi-line dump of each message as a hex + ASCII table. Not exactly pleasant fo production use, but can be useful for debugging.

## Spring Actuator HTTP trace

If you have Spring Actuator in your project, is supports [tracing of HTTP requests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-http-tracing.html). The trace information is sent to a `HttpTraceRepository` bean. By default it's a `InMemoryHttpTraceRepository` that holds the last 100 traces.

You can leverage that by implementing your own `HttpTraceRepository` or a decorator to it that will add logging of the traces. You need to register it as a bean - it will replace the autoconfigured `InMemoryHttpTraceRepository`.

Note that the HTTP traces only have a limited set of information about the request and response, eg. you don't have access to request/response body or size.

A solution that I ended up implementing looks like this:

```
@Bean
public HttpTraceRepository httpTraceRepository() {
    return new AccessLoggingHttpTraceRepositoryDecorator(
            new InMemoryHttpTraceRepository(),
            LoggerFactory.getLogger("netty.Access"),
            new HttpTraceLogFormatter()
    );
}

public class AccessLoggingHttpTraceRepositoryDecorator implements HttpTraceRepository {

    private HttpTraceRepository delegate;
    private Logger logger;
    private HttpTraceLogFormatter formatter;

    public AccessLoggingHttpTraceRepositoryDecorator(HttpTraceRepository delegate, Logger logger, HttpTraceLogFormatter formatter) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.logger = logger;
        this.formatter = formatter;
    }

    @Override
    public List<HttpTrace> findAll() {
        return delegate.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void add(HttpTrace trace) {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            try {
                logger.debug(formatter.format(trace));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Failed to log trace " + trace, e);
            }
        }
        delegate.add(trace);
    }
}

public class HttpTraceLogFormatter {
    public String format(HttpTrace trace) {
        // TODO implement this according to your preference
        return ...;
    }
}
```

With this approach you can get an almost [Common Log Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) message.

You may need to adjust in your `application.yml` what is included in the trace object by specifying

```
management:
  trace:
    http:
      include: REQUEST_HEADERS, RESPONSE_HEADERS, PRINCIPAL, REMOTE_ADDRESS, TIME_TAKEN
```

By default only `REQUEST_HEADERS, RESPONSE_HEADERS, COOKIE_HEADERS, TIME_TAKEN` are included.

## Your own access logging WebFilter

Spring Boot Actuator implements tracing with the help of [`HttpTraceWebFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/web/trace/reactive/HttpTraceWebFilter.java). If you don't want to use the Actuator's solution, you may take inspiration from the source code of the `HttpTraceWebFilter` and implement your own `WebFilter`. Expose it as a Spring bean and it will be automatically registered with Netty.

Answer (score 1):

Support for access logs has been added to the latest version of Reactor Netty.
Just update you Reactor version to `<reactor-bom.version>Bismuth-SR11</reactor-bom.version>`
Then you just need to enable logging of `reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog` into `access_log.log` using whatever logging framework you are using.

See here for details: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/301#issuecomment-418402375

Answer (score 1):

Enable netty access log using Java System Property,

`-Dreactor.netty.http.server.accessLogEnabled=true`

and you can have logging system configured to have a separate access log file.

Below is an example log4j2 configuration.

```
 <RollingRandomAccessFile name="ACCESS_LOG" fileName="access.log"
                                 filePattern="$${date:yyyy-MM}/access-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
                                 append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%t] %d{dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p %-15c{1} [%X]: %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="4"/>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

```
 <logger name="reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog" level="INFO" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ACCESS_LOG"/>
        </logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending the excellent answer from [Adam Michalik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/466738/adam-michalik), I just want to mention that using the JVM argument `-Dreactor.netty.http.server.accessLogEnabled=true` along with the logger `reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog` worked for me with Greenwich but not with Finchley.

I'm using Spring Cloud Gateway v2.1.2, so I guess this makes sense considering the *Release Trains* section of [Spring Cloud](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud).